# C++ array elements order of construction

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

Are there any guarantees in C++ about the order in which array elements are constructed?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  A() { cout << this << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  cout << "[0] is " << new A[3];
}
```

prints out

```
0x602010
0x602011
0x602012
[0] is 0x602010
```

implying that the elements were constructed in the sequence [0], [1] and [2].  Is that order guaranteed by the language?

Comment: Arrays are simply contiguous locations in memory where each element in the array is accessed by ((location of first element of the array) + (subscript * sizeof(whatever type it is))), so I would say yes

Comment: Yes. I'd make an answer out of that, but then I'd have to look for a reference, and I don't feel like doing that right now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's guaranteed by C++11 12.6/3 ([class.init]/3):

> When an array of class objects is initialized (either explicitly or implicitly) and the elements are initialized
>   by constructor, the constructor shall be called for each element of the array, **following the subscript order**

Comment: This clause is rather important for *destruction* in the event of an exception during one of the constructions.

Comment: And, importantly, they are destructed in the reverse order.  This includes if an exception is thrown during construction.  E.g: arr[0] is constructed, arr[1] is constructed, arr[2] throws during construction, arr[1] is destructed, arr[0] is destructed.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.delete#6
In the case of an array, the elements will be destroyed in order of decreasing address (that is, in reverse order of the completion of their constructor (...).